How do I use the "built-in" yyerror() function from flex/bison?
I created my own. It works fine. However, I want to use the default yyerror() function provided by flex/bison. I am using GNU C on Windows 11.

I have never been aware of a flex/bison provided yyerror, it is my understanding that it must be provided.

The system-provided version of yyerror() is similar to this:
void yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

Your version will be better.
The return type might be int because of ancient history. The value returned is unlikely to be significant.
The -lfl library for Flex provides a default main() function and a default yywrap() function, and that's all.  It does not provide yyerror().
The -ly library for Bison provides a default main() function and a default yyerror(), more or less as shown above.

AFAICR, the only string sent to yyerror() is "syntax error" — there might be a few more now, but once upon a long time ago (in another millennium), that was all.

It still is only "syntax error", unless verbose errors are enabled with %define parse.error detailed.
